# Firebase Functions Config: hide Secret in CLI itself

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I need to set a secret in my functions config but I want to make sure, that this secret cannot be accessed by anyone, even if the person has access to the firebase project and thus the cli itself.

What I mean by that is, if I set the secret in my cli, I can then retrieve this secret `firebase functions:config:get`. There are people who might have access to the firebase cli of this project that should not be able to access this secret.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functions configuration you're referring to is only saved on the local machine.  It will not be checked into source control.  Other developers who use the CLI in the same project, but on different machines, will not be able to see that configuration.

The configuration will be available in the deployed code, however.  If each developer needs a fully isolated configuration at runtime, they should each have their own project to work with.